# What are these horizontal boards screwed to my garage wall studs?

Tags: framing, garage, structural, studs

I've decided to do insulation in my garage and am confused by these random seeming 2x4s that are screwed to one wall. Any structural reason they are just in that spot? Two car garage, and on the wall across from the door.

[image]

Comment: I can't see the screws. Where are the boards actually fastened?

Comment: Torx screws through into the studs. The furthest left stud actually isn't attached, the board just flopping away

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but the full-res photo gives no hint to the presence of _any_ such screws. :)

Comment: Promise they are in there - it's the same as the deck screws and randomly show up all over the the house and garage

Comment: @isherwood This obviously does not matter but I may have found [some indications of screws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whJRf.jpg) on the back two studs. Not relevant to the question.

Comment: Looks like the two lower boards are dirty as if they were stepped on over the years. Seems to be a makeshift ladder.

Comment: The guy who owned my shed before me would put various long tools in the studbays. Maybe storage. Maybe an organizer was on there?

Comment: Are they keeping the insulation in place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No reason they have to be there.  They were likely added for some sort of shelving or mount.  Technically they do add some structural integrity as the framing of a house is quite flimsy without sheathing but there is already sheathing on the exterior wall.

Comment: I agree. Any actual brace in that position would look much different.

Comment: It's a fully detached garage if that makes a difference. Might have been for shelves but the garage was built during a flip so the contractor did this but nothing with it

Comment: @Dan it's possible they used it as some sort of ladder to reach something above.

Comment: @jesse_b or perhaps to hang things on for organizational purposes

Comment: Yep, probably there to support something or hang something from.